# Unable to change workspace settings (Server to Local) in TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I learnt about workspaces & the advantages of local workspaces over server workspaces.

When I try to create a local workspace I found that the dropdown where type of workspace (**Local/Server**) can be selected was disabled. Hence, I tried to change the workspace settings i.e. Server to Local & I got the error msg:

**TF400027: The Team Foundation server to which your team project is connected does not support querying or setting version control settings**

I followed the steps mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/05/set-local-workspaces-as-default-when-upgrading-to-tfs-2012.aspx) to change the settings.

I tried looking up the Internet & TFS help documentation wrt to the error code but dint find anything worthwhile. Surprisingly this error code does not exist in their [documentation](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Faa337645%28v%3Dvs.80%29.aspx&ei=KD0gU-ziM4byrQfk_IGYAg&usg=AFQjCNH4jp8jfUaeTdexyZ9wIaVUQ6Q9Sg).

Could anyone please help me with this?

**UPDATE:** As suggested in the below answer I did a get latest & then tried to change the workspace settings but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure your server is TFS 2012?  That message indicates that your server does not support local workspaces.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: I was presuming we had TFS 2012 installed which wasn't the case. Assumptions are always dangerous! I shall upgrade to TFS 2012 & check.

Answer (score 1):

First guess is that your versions of Client and TFS do not match. [MS TFS Compatibility Notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx)

Comment: @T Freber: I shall check this first thing tomorrow & revert.

Comment: Well, so I did a get latest & then tried to change the workspace settings. But still I'm facing the same issue.